# Need color value visible over map

Tags: colors, gui-design

I need to write some text over google maps image. I try lot off combinations of colors but it is ugly. Can anybody give me a color ( hex value) which visible on that map and looks good ( I have no talent for design at all ) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what Google itself does: write it in black and outline with white. Look closely at words in the image: you'll see thin white outline around all words.